# Why I see no Django log in git-bash?

Tags: django, python-3.x, git-bash, pipenv

I am using Python 3's `print` to log from Django dev server. I should mention that I also tried to configure Django to use the Python logger but without much luck. I am using `pipenv run` but the same happens when I activate the virtual env using `pipenv shell`.

I have a very simple view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
  print('Printing to the console from myapp.views.index')
  return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {
    'message': 'Hello, World!'
  })
```

While everything works perfectly fine in `cmd.exe`, `git-bash` does not display any output from my custom logging. See image below.

[image]

**Why is that? Does it have to deal with the fact that one console is considered a terminal (`tty`) and the other is not?**